# Irssi IRC client: ignore text pattern in channel

Tags: irssi

How do I ignore only lines containing the exact phrase "This is text" in a channel?

should I do:

/ignore -word this is text

?

Answer (score 4):

```
/ignore -regexp -pattern "This is text" *
```

Comment: This almost correct, but just a comment, if you want to ignore things just on one channel, use ***/ignore -regexp -pattern "this is text" #channel***